# How to implement the code in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert data in codeigniter.

Here is my view:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name[]">
<input type="text" placeholder="Work Name" name="work[]">
```

Here is my Model

```
public function add_work(){
$names = $_POST['name'];
$works = $_POST['work'];

foreach($names as $key => $name){
            $work = $works[$key];

            $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO work(name,work) values ( '$name','$work')");
   }
}
```

Codeigniter refuse to use mysql query. How to fix that. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have more than one textboxes with `name="name[]"` and `name="work[]"`??

Comment: Yes. I have more than one textboxes

Comment: Hey you need to **connect mysql** first if you use it like this.

Comment: Please add code here.

Comment: Bro, I'm using codeigniter framework. I already connected in database.php

Comment: Yes, but codeigniter internally use database.php not in case you directly use `mysql_*` in your model.

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated in CI3. Use `mysqli` instead

Comment: how to use that for multiple array

Comment: Try this if you want to query in codeigniter `$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');` for the reference check out this: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your controller

```
class CommonController extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('common_model'); //load your model my model is "common model"
  }

 public function add_work(){
 $names = $_POST['name'];
 $works = $_POST['work'];

 foreach($names as $key => $name){
             $name= "your specified name";
             $insertdata = array();
             $insertdata['work'] = $works[$key];
             $insertdata['name'] = $name;
             $this->common_model->insert($insertdata);
        //$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO work(name,work) values ( '$name','$work')");
            }
  }
}
```

and in your model "common_model.php"

```
 class Common_model extends CI_Model {

/**
 * Constructor 
 *
 */
   public function __construct()
 {
     parent::__construct();

  }//Controller End
  public function insert($insertData=array()){
     $this->db->insert('work', $insertData);
  }


}
```

Comment: Getting `Undefined variable: insertData`

Comment: now getting `You must use the "set" method to update an entry.`

Comment: do you have any prefixes to the table name?

Comment: ok try this inside insert function in model.

$this->db->set($insertData);
    $this->db->insert('work');